# Stripe Payment Integration with flutter_bloc architecture getting asynchronous suspension error on handling Event

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, bloc

So I was integrating the flutter stripe payment systems, and it used to work a couple of weeks ago with payments getting fully completed, however, now I get an asynchronous suspension error on handling Event using the flutter_bloc dart extension. I've been careful with the asyncs and awaits and have carefully followed bloc's architecture per their [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating). Nothing is working however I do it.

This is the error that I'm getting:

````
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)
<html><head>
^
#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#6      PaymentBloc._callPayEndpointMethodId
package:flutter_app_social/…/paymentbloc/payment_bloc.dart:136
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      PaymentBloc._onPaymentCreateIntent
package:flutter_app_social/…/paymentbloc/payment_bloc.dart:38
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent
package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:226
<asynchronous suspension>

/// Register event handler for an event of type `E`.
  /// There should only ever be one event handler per event type `E`.
  ///
  /// ```dart
  /// abstract class CounterEvent {}
  /// class CounterIncrementPressed extends CounterEvent {}
  ///
  /// class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  ///   CounterBloc() : super(0) {
  ///     on<CounterIncrementPressed>((event, emit) => emit(state + 1));
  ///   }
  /// }
  /// ```
  ///
  /// * A [StateError] will be thrown if there are multiple event handlers
  /// registered for the same type `E`.
  ///
  /// By default, events will be processed concurrently.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  /// * [EventTransformer] to customize how events are processed.
  /// * [package:bloc_concurrency](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_concurrency) for an
  /// opinionated set of event transformers.
  ///
````

and here's my source code:

**payment_state.dart**

```
part of 'payment_bloc.dart';

enum PaymentStatus { initial, loading, success, failure }

class PaymentState extends Equatable {
  final PaymentStatus status;
  final CardFieldInputDetails inputDetails;

  const PaymentState({
    this.status = PaymentStatus.initial,
    this.inputDetails = const CardFieldInputDetails(complete: false),
  });

  PaymentState copyWith({
    PaymentStatus? status,
    CardFieldInputDetails? inputDetails,
  }) {
    return PaymentState(
      status: status ?? this.status,
      inputDetails: inputDetails ?? this.inputDetails,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, inputDetails];
}
```

**payment_event.dart**

```
part of 'payment_bloc.dart';

abstract class PaymentEvent extends Equatable {
  const PaymentEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class PaymentStart extends PaymentEvent {}

class PaymentCreateIntent extends PaymentEvent {
  final BillingDetails billingDetails;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> items;

  const PaymentCreateIntent({
    required this.billingDetails,
    required this.items,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [billingDetails, items];
}

class PaymentConfirmIntent extends PaymentEvent {
  final String clientSecret;

  const PaymentConfirmIntent({
    required this.clientSecret,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [clientSecret];
}
```

**payment_bloc.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

part 'payment_event.dart';
part 'payment_state.dart';

class PaymentBloc extends Bloc<PaymentEvent, PaymentState> {
  PaymentBloc() : super(const PaymentState()) {
    on<PaymentStart>(_onPaymentStart);
    on<PaymentCreateIntent>(_onPaymentCreateIntent);
    on<PaymentConfirmIntent>(_onPaymentConfirmIntent);
  }

  void _onPaymentStart(
    PaymentStart event,
    Emitter<PaymentState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: PaymentStatus.initial));
  }

  void _onPaymentCreateIntent(
    PaymentCreateIntent event,
    Emitter<PaymentState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: PaymentStatus.loading));

    final paymentMethod = await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
      params: PaymentMethodParams.card(
        paymentMethodData:
            PaymentMethodData(billingDetails: event.billingDetails),
      ),
    );

    final paymentIntentResults = await _callPayEndpointMethodId(
      useStripeSdk: true,
      paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
      currency: 'usd',
      items: event.items,
    );

    print(paymentIntentResults);

    if (paymentIntentResults['error'] != null) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: PaymentStatus.failure),
      );
    }

    if (paymentIntentResults['clientSecret'] != null &&
        paymentIntentResults['requiresAction'] == null) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: PaymentStatus.success),
      );
    }

    if (paymentIntentResults['clientSecret'] != null &&
        paymentIntentResults['requiresAction'] == null) {
      final String clientSecret = paymentIntentResults['clientSecret'];
      add(
        PaymentConfirmIntent(clientSecret: clientSecret),
      );
    }
  }

  void _onPaymentConfirmIntent(
    PaymentConfirmIntent event,
    Emitter<PaymentState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      final paymentIntent =
          await Stripe.instance.handleNextAction(event.clientSecret);

      if (paymentIntent.status == PaymentIntentsStatus.RequiresConfirmation) {
        Map<String, dynamic> results = await _callPayEndpointIntentId(
          paymentIntentId: paymentIntent.id,
        );
        if (results['error'] != null) {
          emit(state.copyWith(status: PaymentStatus.failure));
        } else {
          emit(state.copyWith(status: PaymentStatus.success));
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: PaymentStatus.failure),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _callPayEndpointIntentId({
    required String paymentIntentId,
  }) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
      'https://us-central1-evental-acdgnf69.cloudfunctions.net/StripePayEndpointIntentId',
    );

    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json.encode(
        {
          'paymentIntentId': paymentIntentId,
        },
      ),
    );
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _callPayEndpointMethodId({
    required bool useStripeSdk,
    required String paymentMethodId,
    required String currency,
    required List<Map<String, dynamic>> items,
  }) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
      'https://us-central1-evental-acdgnf69.cloudfunctions.net/StripePayEndpointMethodId',
    );

    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json.encode(
        {
          'useStripeSdk': useStripeSdk,
          'paymentMethodId': paymentMethodId,
          'currency': currency,
          'items': items,
        },
      ),
    );
    print(response.body);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
}
```

the final piece of the puzzle is my stripe_form_page.dart, which is basically a card form page for all the details and a button to initiate the events:

```
ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        (controller.details.complete)
                            ? context.read<PaymentBloc>().add(
                                  const PaymentCreateIntent(...
```

I suppose in some way the state of the events is not getting changed, so it doesn't recognise it later on, however, I've followed the way it has been done in the documentation.

Comment: Have you checked whether anything is wrong with your server and requests are hitting it successfully?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using firebase functions to operate as a server and from what I can see at the dashboard, the endpoints are getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've figured this out already or not, but I had this same problem. For me, I had a typo in the JSON I was passing and it didn't match what I was passing in the cloud function.